# Cupy error : cudaErrorIllegalAddress - an illegal memory access was encountered

Tags: neural-network, chainer, cupy

Training a feed forward network on GPU using Chainer. After training some batches, getting aerror "CUDARuntimeError: cudaErrorIllegalAddress: an illegal memory access was encountered".

only 1.5GB out of 11GB gpu memory is in use.
Once the error is encountered, attempt to create a small cupy array too fails with same error.

Chainer : v6.5.0
Cupy : v6.5.0

Comment: Supply your code and specifically point to the line where the error is generated.

Comment: When supplying the code make sure you supply a minimal reproducible example (reduce it to the simplest example that still generates the same error).

Comment: Hi @Jose, were you using SSD model in Chainer?